# Handle an error and redirect output in shell

Tags: sh

In a shell script, I run a command which may fail. For example, here I work in a new directory (`mkdir foo && cd foo`), so a `make` command can not success.

I handle errors with `||`:

```
make || echo "No target"
```

...and I print output (stdout and stderr) in a log file with `tee`:

```
make 2>&1 | tee foo.log
```

How to do the two at once?

- `make 2>&1 | tee foo.log || echo "No target"`: write the error in the logfile, but do not print "No target" in the console;
- `make || echo "No target" 2>&1 | tee foo.log`: print the error and "No target" in the console, but write only "No target" in the logfile, not the error itself.

Comment: Actually, you should not run `make` at all if the `cd` fails, instead of simply checking if `make` fails. `mkdir foo && cd foo || { echo "can't cd foo"; exit 1; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bash, you can check `PIPE_STATUS[0]` to get the status of the `make` in `make 2>&1 | tee`.  If you want portability, you can do something like:

```
{ make 2>&1 || echo 'No target' > /dev/tty; } 2>&1 | tee foo.log
```

But 'No target' is probably the wrong error message, and this will just confuse anyone who encounters it.

If you do want 'No target' to be in `foo.log` as well, use:

```
{ make 2>&1 || echo 'No target'; } | tee foo.log
```

but to reiterate: 'No target' is a useless error message which is probably not accurate.

Comment: Thanks! Of course this was an example, I don't want to just print "No target".